# How to collapse and change view in android? (not toolbar)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to change my view with another view when collapsed. I already did almost the same thing by using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but it works only with `Toolbar`. When i replaced `Toolbar` with another view or added view as child of `Toolbar`, it doesn't work properly.

I tried already this code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   >

   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       android:id="@+id/aaaa"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="350dp"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
       app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       >

       <ImageView
           app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
           android:src="@drawable/firework"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="350dp" />

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:title="@string/recent_news"
           >

       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

### Expanded view:

[image: Expanded view]

### This is what I want when scrolled:

[image: This is what I want when scrolled]

### This is what happened when view changed with toolbar or added as child:

[image: This is what happened when view changed with toolbar or added as child]

Answer (score 1):

if You want to change a view when `AppBarLayout` is Expanded you can listen to its state by `addOnOffsetChangedListener` in your case

1- create your own `OnOffsetChangedListener`

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    public enum State {
        EXPANDED,
        COLLAPSED,
        IDLE
    }

    private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

    @Override
    public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
        } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
                onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
            }
            mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
}
```

2- add the `OffsetChangedListener` to `AppBarLayout`

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
        if (state == State.EXPANDED) {

             //appbar is expand show  the view  when it expanded 
        } else if (state == State.COLLAPSED) {
        //appbar is collapsed show  the view  when it collapsed. 

});
```